# Increasing the number of epochs to reach the performance goal while training neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am training the neural network with input vector of 85*650 and target vector of 26*650. Here is the list of parameters that I have used

```
     net.trainParam.max_fail = 6;
     net.trainParam.min_grad=1e-5;
     net.trainParam.show=10;
     net.trainParam.lr=0.9;
     net.trainParam.epochs=13500;
     net.trainParam.goal=0.001;
```

Number of hidden nodes=76

As you can see ,I have set the number of epochs to 13500. Is it OK to set the number of epochs to such a large number?. Performance goal is not reaching if the number of epochs is decreased and I am getting a bad classification while testing.

Comment: what do you get while reaching 13500? a good or bad classification?

Comment: @NKN I am get a pretty good classification.

Comment: Then, that's a good epoch for your structure. You may increase the number of neurons in the hidden layer, for example go for 85x2 or even more (if the 85 is the number of variables no the samples). In such structure you will probably reach the same result with lower number of trials (lower epochs)

Comment: This is a wrong way of looking at it in my opinion. A good algorithm should perform better when it is let run for a longer time. This tendency to cut the algorithm short and expecting good classification and generalization is very hacky. In my mind, an algorithm should be allowed to run for as long as you have patience for and the issues of generalization should be handled as a separate problem (through dropout or otherwise). So, 13500 or 1 million epochs, if it is something you have patience for, go right ahead. But, if it doesn't generalize or overfits, don't cut down epochs as a solution

Comment: I have kept on increasing the number of epochs by trail and error method until the performance goal is met. Is that the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to focus on the number of epochs.  Instead, you should have, at least, two sets of data: one for training and another for testing.  Use the testing set to get a feel for how well your ANN is performing and how many epochs is needed to get a decent ANN.

For example, you want to stop training when performance on your testing set as levelled-off or has begun to decrease (get worse).  This would be evidence of over-learning which is the reason why more epochs is not always better.